# Python Thread OpenCV

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to get a python script able to start and stop as needed videocapture. I am trying to do it with Thread

But I have not been able to get it. I hope someone could help me.
In my code I can never recover img window after finish 1
This is what I have done.

```
import cv2
import time
from threading import Thread

class Video:
    def __init__(self):       
        self.camara1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.iniciar_video=True
        self.estoy_vivo=True
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.mantiene_vivo, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def mantiene_vivo(self):
        self.inicia_video()
        while self.estoy_vivo:
            time.sleep(10) 

    def detener(self):
        self.iniciar_video=False

    def inicia_video(self):
        print("Iniciando")

        self.iniciar_video=True

        self.camara1.open(0)

        while self.iniciar_video:

            ret1,captura1= self.camara1.read() 
            if(ret1):
                cv2.imshow('img',captura1)

            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

            if key == ord("q"):

                self.iniciar_video=False
                self.detener()
                break    
        cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
        self.camara1.release()

ObjVideo = Video()
time.sleep(10) 
print("Finish 1")
ObjVideo.detener() 
time.sleep(10) 
ObjVideo.inicia_video()
time.sleep(10)
print("Finish 2")
ObjVideo.detener() 
time.sleep(10) 
ObjVideo.inicia_video()
```

Comment: I don't speak Python, but try passing 30 to `cv2.waitKey` instead of 1. Also, you seem to set `set.iniciar_video=False` just before calling `set.detener()` which does the same thing anyway. Also, not sure if Python might optimise away `while self.iniciar_video:` if that variable is set in another thread - is there anything like `C`'s `volatile` or `atomic` in Python?

Comment: I don't speak Spanish, but it seems your function names are misleading. I assume "inicia_video" would be "start_video" -- but it runs the whole capture loop and displays images. | "estoy_vivo" never changes, so after the first `ObjVideo.detener()` the thread gets stuck in an infinite loop of `sleep`s. Then you call `ObjVideo.inicia_video()` from the main thread... and run the capture loop on the main thread, rather than the worker. Depending on platform, using the video capture from multiple threads might not be making it happy.

Comment: Thank you. I will try what you say and I will tell you my result.

Comment: Hi. I did what you recommended but I got the same. When inicia_video finishes the thread dies. When I try to create a new one then cv2.imshow never starts again. Just when first object is launched. It is like cv2.imshow can not be used more than one time.

Comment: Hi  it looks like cv2.imshow does not work inside a thread. So I made a thread to read videocapture and outside of thread I show it in imshow. Now it works. Thank you.